# select based on values in sub-object array

Tags: json, select, jq

I'm trying to automate the process for updating AWS Lambda layers and the functions that use them.  To get a list of functions that use a particular layer I'm parsing the JSON output of the AWS CLI when listing the current functions in my account.  Calling `aws lambda list-functions` returns a JSON block similar to the example below (I have deliberately removed some irrelevant content to focus on the issue):

```
{
  "Functions": [
    {
      "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
      },
      "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:function:function-1"
    },
    {
      "Layers": [
        {
          "CodeSize": 11359101,
          "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:layer:layer1:12"
        }
      ],
      "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
      },
      "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:function:function-2"
    },
    {
      "Layers": [
        {
          "CodeSize": 11359101,
          "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:layer:layer1:12"
        },
        {
          "CodeSize": 11359101,
          "Arn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:layer:layer2:5"
        }
      ],
      "TracingConfig": {
        "Mode": "PassThrough"
      },
      "FunctionArn": "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2:000000000000:function:function-3"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the example above I have three functions defined, two of which make use of at least one layer.  What I need to do is get a list of `FunctionArn` values for functions that use a specific layer.  So far I have been able to filter out the function that doesn't use any layers using this command:

```
aws lambda list-functions | jq '.Functions[] | select(.Layers)'
```

What I really need to do is create a `select()` statement that can filter inside the "Layers" array from the top level:

```
aws lambda list-functions | jq '.Functions[] | select(.Layers[] | contains("layer2"))'
```

https://jqplay.org/s/SiFSE3RxZV

But I keep getting "Cannot iterate over null" error messages that I think are coming from inside the `select()` statement?

The plan is to filter the list down to functions that use the particular layer in question, then return the `FunctionArn` value for each result for use in my script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From elements of `Functions`, select ones that have a `Layers` key whose value -an array- contains at least one object having `layer2` as a substring in its `Arn` field -a string-, and extract their `FunctionArn`s. E.g:

```
.Functions[] | select(has("Layers") and any(.Layers[].Arn; index("layer2"))) | .FunctionArn
```